# need help with limit of integer part ??

Tags: limits, integers

I need help with that limit of integer part !!

> $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} x^2E\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Where $E(x)$ means the integer part of $x$.

Comment: What does $E(\frac{1}{x})$ mean?

Comment: Do you mean? $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2[\frac{1}{x}]$

Comment: I see nothing about integer part here. This will be closed and downvoted both because it is unclear and because you show no effort of your own. Please edit the question to fix both of those things and we may be able to help,

Comment: @EthanBolker $E(a)$ is a notation for integer part of $a$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Sorry, its a notation for integer part

Comment: Respect users. Do not downvote chemically.

Answer (score 3):

For $x>1$, we have

$$0 <\frac {1}{x}<1$$

thus
$$(\forall x>1) \;\; E \left(\frac {1}{x}\right)=0$$

and
$$x^2E \left(\frac {1}{x}\right)=0$$

The limit is zero